# Trying to check if a database cell contains a certain string then change the badge color

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

So Iam using vuex and laravel for this project and i have had some difficulties with trying to change the badge depending on the displayed data in my dashboard. Currently my dashboard looks like this:

[image]

Now what i would like to happen is when an Error Message contains for instance the string 99012. That the badge color according to the Error message code. I havent been able to make the {"Result":[{"ERRORS":"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049"}]} in JSON format that is why its been displayed like this.

Currently my Controller looks like this:

```
class GencomController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     *
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //
//        $log = Log::get('RESPONSE');
        // Get all the Response rows from database.
        $data = Log::all();

        // Convert data into json array
        //$decoded = json_encode($data, true);
        
        $decoded = json_decode($data);

        return ($decoded);
    }
```

This is how my store.js looks:

```
    api_logs: {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
    },
```

and here is my .vue component:

```
    <div class="mt-8 flex flex-col">
      <div class="-my-2 -mx-4 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
        <div class="inline-block py-2 align-middle">
          <div class="overflow-auto relative shadow-sm ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5">
            <table class="table-fixed divide-y divide-gray-300">
              <thead class="bg-gray-50">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="w-1/15 py-3.5 pl-4 pr-3 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 sm:pl-6 lg:pl-8">ID</th>
                <th scope="col" class="w-1/13 px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Date & Time</th>
                <th scope="col" class=" px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Error Message</th>
                <th scope="col" class=" px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Status Badge</th>
                <th scope="col" class=" px-3 py-3.5 text-left text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col" class=" relative py-3.5 pl-3 pr-4 sm:pr-6 lg:pr-8">
                  <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="divide-y divide-gray-200 bg-white">
              <tr v-for="log in logs" :key="log.APIGROUPNO">
                <td class="w-1/15 py-4 pl-4 pr-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sm:pl-6 lg:pl-8">{{ log.APIGROUPNO }}</td>
                <td class=" px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.DATETIMEEXECUTED }}</td>
<!--                <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.JSONBDY }}</td>-->
                <td class="break-all px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">{{ log.RESPONSE }}</td>
                <td class="break-all px-3 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500"><span class="bg-red-100 text-red-800 text-xs font-semibold mr-2 px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded dark:bg-red-200 dark:text-red-900">Error</span></td>

                <td class="relative  py-4 pl-3 pr-4 text-right text-sm font-medium sm:pr-6 lg:pr-8">
                  <a href="#" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900"
                  >Edit<span class="sr-only">, {{ log.APIGROUPNO }}</span></a
                  >
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is my Model:

```
class Log extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $connection = 'gencom';
    protected $table = 'GMAPILOG';
    protected $primaryKey = 'APIGROUPNO';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $casts = ["Result"=>'array'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'APIGROUPNO',
        'DATETIMEEXECUTED',
        'PACKAGENAME',
        'TOKEN',
        'APINAME',
        'PARAMETERLIST',
        'JSONBDY',
        'RESPONSE'
    ];

}
```

The json response i get returned from the db:

```
RESPONSE: "{\"Result\":[{\"ERRORS\":\"99012: Weborder number already exists : 20211049\"}]}"
```

So to make a quick summary, i would like the badge color to change according to the code gotten in the message. I have tried it for a while but i cant seem to figure it out as i do struggle a bit with vuex. I hope some could explain me their thought process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please remove the images and paste in the code? StackOverflow has code blocks for code, which makes it much easier to read your question.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan Yes, i made the changes, thank you for looking in to it :)